# Symbolic link issues on Laravel/Homestead/Windows

Tags: laravel, vagrant, symlink, homestead

I'm having problems displaying images stored in the storage folder. At the moment all file uploads are configured to end up in the following folder:

storage\app\public

And I'm trying to access them as follows:

http://homestead.vaniloapp-demo/storage/6/testimage.jpg

However, this results in a 404.

If I run: `php artisan storage:link` I get the following error message:

"The "public/storage" directory already exists."

I have tied a bunch of different tips and tricks from various other threads including unlinking the public folder using `unlink storage` and then attempting to link it again manually using `ln -s ../storage/app/public storage` but that results in the following error:

"failed to create symbolic link 'storage': Protocol error"

Have tried using Sudo, have tied launching CMD as Administrator.

I'm running Homestead and Vagrant for Windows.

Thanks in advance!

Mika

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the best steps I've come up with

1. Unlink storage on your current Vagrant instance
2. Halt vagrant `vagrant halt`
3. Run CMD/Terminal as Administration (Right click > Run as administrator)
4. Go to your Homestead folder and start vagrant `vagrant up --provision`
5. SSH into vagrant `vagrant ssh` while still in the same CMD/Terminal
6. CD into your Laravel directory and run `php artisan storage:link`

I've seen people have issues while the vagrant box has not been started in the CMD administration mode.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was just about to reply, that I have already tried this before and it didn't work but decided to give it one more go. Not sure what I did differently this time but either way it's now working perfectly!!

Comment: I had to reboot between steps 2 and 3 to get it working. Otherwise, this helped me to get storage link to work.

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time around this problem also.

I am also on a Windows machine and have my Development environment set with Laravel and Homestead.

To create the storage link, after having the Vagrant machine up **vagrant up**, I have entered in my Vagrant machine with the **vagrant ssh** command and then cd'd into the project's directory **cd /home/vagrant/project**.
When in the Project's directory run **php artisan storage:link** to generate the symblink.

Now, if you do an **ls -la public**, you can see that the path to the files is absolute - That will not work in Windows! The paths are not the same.

To solve this, I've created the symblink manually to make it relative and not absolute.
Go to the public folder **cd /home/vagrant/project/public**.
Create the symblink manually **ln -s ../storage/app/public/ storage**.

Answer (score 0):

This is how we solved it, slightly different from opinatus's:

1. Halt vagrant `vagrant halt`
2. Reboot
3. Run Virtual Box as administrator
4. Open terminal as administrator
5. Run `vagrant up`
6. Run `vagrant ssh`
7. CD into project's root folder
8. Run `php artisan storage:link`

This way worked for us. I think the main reason is starting VirtualBox as admin *before* starting the homestead.